# Max width changes when changing the screen resolution

Tags: html, css, angular

I have this simple `img` that I set to `max-width: 150%`

When I'm in resolution  of 90% it looks great, on 100% it get smaller and on 110% it disappears

How can I fix it?

```
<h1><img class="img-logo" src="../../assets/images/HomePage/Group.png"> </h1>

    .img-logo {
          max-width: 150%;
          margin-right: -90px;
          margin-bottom: 80px;
          overflow: hidden;

}
```

[image]

Comment: You can fix this by using a more reliable value than `150%` ... why not save the logo in the size you need it? Why not use SVG for this?

Comment: @cloned what the differnt in this case for svg?

Comment: SVG is best for displaying graphics like you have. It scales without issues. And you can use it directly in HTML.

Comment: Why do you use it with h1?